# Multiple IntentServices listening to one unique Intent

Tags: android, intentservice, intentfilter

I want to have multiple IntentServices to listen to one Intent and process it on various ways. Currently, only one IntentService receives the Intent and consumes it. Any ideas? Is there a flag or something? I don't want to implement an Intent for every Service.